# Unable to import single csv file that contains unicode data to multiple tables using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv, unicode, import-from-excel

I'm trying to import single csv file that contains unicode data to multiple tables using php and mysql .I'm able to insert data to multiple tables but doesnot support unicode. I have csv file with  nepali data . Please help me.
Thanks in advance
[image]

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: charset=utf-8');
  require_once('conn.php');
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

          $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
          $handle = fopen($file, "r");
          // echo $file;die;
          $c = 0;
          while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
          // while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== false)
                    {
                         $filesop = array_map("utf8_encode", $filesop);
          // var_dump($filesop);die;
          $id = $filesop[0];
          // echo $id;die;
          $registration_date = $filesop[1];

          $building_use_id = $filesop[2];
          $building_category = $filesop[3];


          $a=utf8_encode($registration_date);

          $bps_registration_newregistration = "insert into bps_registration_newregistration(id,registration_date) values ('$id','$registration_date')";
          $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,$bps_registration_newregistration);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 $bps_registration_application = "insert into bps_registration_application(reg_id,registration_date,building_use_id,building_category) values ('$id','$a','$building_use_id','$building_category')";
          $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($conn,$bps_registration_application);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);


         $c = $c + 1;
           }

            if($bps_registration_newregistration  && $bps_registration_application ){
               echo "sucess";
             } 

     else
     {
            echo "Sorry! Unable to impo.";
          }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
        <p class="help-block">Only Excel/CSV File Import.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: Can you show the first row of the CSV in a text file? Maybe it's tab separated instead of comma, or uses another separator

Comment: I converted csv file to text file and i added image in question. @aynber

Comment: I used utf-8 in mysql database but still it gave me problem  @Marc Dix

Comment: Yup, it's tab separated instead of comma separated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

Your file is tab-separated, not comma-separated, so you need to tell the function that:

```
while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== false)
```

Comment: I still got same issue. How can isolve it as well asunicode issue?  @aynber

Comment: It's still giving you undefined offsets? You may need to `var_dump($filesop)` to see what it all contains.

Comment: When i var_dump inside while loop, and upload csv file and click upload button , it says me to save file in my computer. @aynber

Comment: That is weird. It should not ask you to download anything

Comment: But i'm unable to obtain data from csv file.  It shows only header  . @aynber array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(84) "id,registration_date,contactno,latitude,building_use_id,building_category,ch_name_np"
}

Comment: The header is CSV, and the rest is tab? You need to get the file into a consistent format.

Comment: Can I ask another question? @aynber

Answer (score 0):

Its your database Unicode format issue, change your database encoding to UTF-8 with General_CI and same for the targeted tables. My recommendation will be to use Navicat to do that as it will be simple to convert the MySQL Database and tables formatting.

Remember to Change formatting of database as well its tables also.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing PHP code with fgetcsv, use MySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE` to pull it directly into a table.  Be sure to create the table with `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or `utf8mb4`).

Use `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` to fetch the hex of some of the Nepali text so we can verify its encoding.  Assuming it is using the Devanagari alphabet, I would expect to see mostly `E0 A4 xx` and `E0 A5 xx` in the hex.  That's 3 bytes per character.

Even if you get it loaded via PHP code, verify the table that way.  If you have problems, see [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)